# PHP - Setting a variable to a equal a function, without running it

Tags: php, functional-programming

Do you know if there is a way of doing the following in php without executing the function?

I would like $test to equal the function, not its result.

```
$test = helloWorld();

function helloWorld() {
    echo "HelloWorld";
}
```

Comment: Bud, to make life a little easier, make a class create the functions within it and simply call the functions within the class

Comment: You can do `$test = function () { echo "HelloWorld"; }`, this is called an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: @Robbie if you don't want to execute the function in your own words. Why create the function in the first place ?

Comment: I don't want it executing at the moment it's defined, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest way to achieve this is to use a **variable function**:

```
function helloWorld() {
    echo "HelloWorld";
}

$test = 'helloWorld';
$test();
```

Using an **anonymous function** could also do it. Notice the `;` after the function declaration.

```
$test = function () {
    echo "HelloWorld";
};

$test();
```

See [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) and [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks AymDev. I'll end up using both of these methods I reckon, the first for the predefined Wordpress functions I'm having to use, and the second for my own functions.

Comment: @Robbie I answered for your needs but you maybe should just call WP functions normally and declare your custom functions in a more classic way. Happy coding !

Comment: After much messing about, I've concluded exactly that AymDev.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

```
$test = function() {
    echo "HelloWorld";
};

// To call it:
$test();
```

I read all that functional stuff, but I sometimes despair about how little of it went in!

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following

```
<?php

$test = "helloWorld";

function helloWorld () : void
{
    echo "Hello World!";
}

// Execute the code on demand using:
$this->{$test}();
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, which does exactly what I need, though I'm not OO, so don't need the $this->{};

Comment: @Robbie But ... this executes the function. How is this exactly what you need?

Comment: @Robbie have a look at my answer :)

Comment: kerbholz - It doesn't execute the function on its creation, only when I give it the $this->{$test}(); which is much later in the code, which is what I'm after.

Answer (score -1):

Say for example i have a page called functions.php
now in functions im going to create the following

```
//functions.php page
class functions
{
    public function helloWorld() {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
```

No that i have a class and a function inside it i would like to call it on my index page
so i will now have to do the following

```
//index.php page
$test = new functions(); //calls the class functions 

//here is the part you would like
//$test->helloWorld(); this calls the helloWorld function but does nothing.

//now you can store this into a variable
$helloWorld = $test->helloWorld();
```

Comment: Thanks JamesBond. I'm trying to get away from OO like I'm being told. The imperative/functional principle is the same though, so thanks for the help.